# Django ManyToMany queries

Tags: python, django

Might be a silly question but I'm new to django.

This is my user,

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    username = models.CharField(null=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
```

And this is my `Room` object which has a `ManyToMany` relationship with the `User`

```
class Room(Base):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

From this model its easy to get all Users in a room. My questions is how do I get all Rooms for an user. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the reverse relation:

```
my_user.room_set.all()
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to change the reverse relation name

```
class Room(Base):
    ''' fields above '''
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='get_rooms')
```

Now you use the reverse relation with the `related_name`:

```
the_user.get_rooms.all()
```